# how to change layout view controller?

Tags: iphone, ios, layout, uiviewcontroller

I make a application for the iphone and I use UIStoryboard.

I have a view that looks like this when the app start

[image]

When I press `Button1` the label `Code 2:` and `textfield` must disappear
I tried the `setHidden` method

This is what happens

[image]

But what I would like to happen is this

[image]

How should I do that?

Comment: You need to set the frame of the your UI controls dynamically

Comment: you have to set the frame of save button and show saved data button where you hide your code 2 label and text field

Comment: get height of uitextfield in button action and do minus (-) height of your two button base on uitextfield height

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After hiding label and textfield and label,you need to set frame of your Save and Show saved Data button by,

```
btnSave.frame=CGRectMake(btnSave.frame.origin.x,btnSave.frame.origin.y - your textfield height, btnSave.frame.size.width, btnSave.frame.size.height);
```

Comment: I've tried it, but now it doesn't work anymore, button stay in the same place

Answer (score 0):

You need to take IBoutlet and set the frame of the your **save** button and **show save data** button  Dynamically